# Lots of failed Static function errors after upgrade to 4.7.13 (Joomla)

Tags: joomla, upgrade, 4.7

Just upgraded from a very old (4.4 something) release to 4.7.13. Lots of things are working, but getting lots of these:

Call to undefined method CRM_Contact_BAO_Query::processSpecialFormValue()

Seems to be just static functions.

Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. There were some old customised files hanging around that are no longer needed.